# GitHub Actions pm2 Issue

Tags: github-actions, pm2

In GitHub Actions, I run `pm2 restart 0` and it shows
[image]

However, in the regular SSH command line (both are running under the same user), it works

[image]

Comment: why do you need use pm2 in a github action?

Comment: Please take a look at [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/14853083)

Comment: To restart my system after I update the code